# How to force "PrintThis" to "Break page"

Tags: php, jquery, printthis

When i'm using Jquery pluggin "PrintThis",
The html function: `<div style='page-break-after:always'></div>`
stops working. Well, "PrintThis", won't break page!
How can i solve this?
Should i put the "Break line", in JS? How?
Is it ok to use the same table id?

**HTML**

```
//Print Btn
<button id="print_btn">btn</button>

//Table 1
<table id="table" class="display">
  <tr><td>Hi</td></tr>
</table>

//Break page here
<div style='page-break-after:always'></div>

//Table 2
<table id="table" class="display">
  <tr><td>Hi</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#print_btn').click(function () {
        $('#table').printThis();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the printThis author. First, you should never use the same id twice, as that's what classes are for. Also, if you want the page break to work, you can wrap both tables and the page break in a container and use printThis on that container.

Comment: @Jason It's a great honour to be writing with you. Your script is very nice! Thank you so much for it. I´ve come up with an easy solution, just added the class "display" to the "break-page-div" and then added it to the JS. Very Usefull... Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, once again the solution for this script was easy to solve. (Just had some sleep on it =)

**HTML**

```
//ADD class "display" and id.
<div class="display" id "break_page" style='page-break-after:always'></div>
```

**JS**

```
//Add id "break_page" to JS
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#print_btn').click(function () {
    $('#table, #break_page').printThis();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`break-after` property is ignored on elements that don't generate box. You should use this style on your `table` instead of a `div`

[See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)